# MS ACCESS SQL: How to do a nested count

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I am trying to count the number of messages userid = 1 did and then COUNT the number of messages of all the other userid and print out the names of the people where the number of messages = the number of messages userid = 1 has.

So I need to do a nested count. I have 2 tables for this. Messages and User.

For example:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM MESSAGES
WHERE user_id = 1
```

And the result is 2.
Then I need

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM MESSAGES
WHERE COUNT(*) = 2
```

How do I do a nested count for this so I can do something like

```
SELECT USER.user_name
FROM MESSAGES INNER JOIN USER ON MESSAGES.user_id = USER.user_id
WHERE COUNT(*) = (    
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM MESSAGES
WHERE user_id = 1
)
```

The above example doesn't work for me. I am using MsAccess. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `HAVING` syntax

```
SELECT USER.user_name
FROM MESSAGES INNER JOIN USER ON MESSAGES.user_id = USER.user_id
GROUP BY MESSAGES.user_id, USER.user_name
HAVING COUNT(*) = (    
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM MESSAGES
WHERE user_id = 1
)
```

Comment: It gives me an error message that says "You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'user_name' as part of an aggregate function." Any idea what that means?

Comment: @NuttyNur Put `USER.user_name` on the `GROUP BY` become `GROUP BY MESSAGES.user_id,USER.user_name`